# Google-Admin-SDK - .Net-Client - cannot set projection parameter for user list

Tags: c#, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm reading our Google-Apps-User like this:

```
UsersResource.ListRequest userrequest = service.Users.List();
userrequest.MaxResults = 250;
userrequest.Customer = "xxxxxxx";
IList<User> gusers = userrequest.Execute().UsersValue;
foreach (var guser in gusers) { .... }
```

No problem so far, I get what I want except the CustomSchema fields.
In the API-Explorer it's easy to set "projection" to "full" and everythin is fine, but in the C#-Code I don't get it how to do it.

If I try this:

```
userrequest.Projection = "FULL";
```

I get this hint:

> ```
> UserResource.ListRequest.ProjectionEnum? ListRequest.Projection
> ```

I know for a true coder is this the solution, but I don't get it.
What do I have to write to get the projection to "full"?
Even in the source code from Google it's just the string (okay, I'm quite new to .Net-coding maybe I miss a lot here)

```
/// <summary>Restrict information returned to a set of selected fields.  </summary>
    [Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("projection", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]
    public virtual System.Nullable<ProjectionEnum> Projection { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Restrict information returned to a set of selected fields.</summary>
    public enum ProjectionEnum
    {
        /// <summary>Includes only the basic metadata fields (e.g., deviceId, serialNumber, status, and
        /// user)</summary>
        [Google.Apis.Util.StringValueAttribute("BASIC")]
        BASIC,
        /// <summary>Includes all metadata fields</summary>
        [Google.Apis.Util.StringValueAttribute("FULL")]
        FULL,
    }
```

Comment: `userrequest.Projection = ProjectionEnum.FULL;`

Comment: Thx for the fast response! When I see I understand - quite easy, good lesson!   ;o)    Strange is, that I get now "...is not in current context"  (translation from the german message) for the ProjectionEnum despite the fact that Google.Apis.Util and Google.Apis.Util.Store are used. Another little hint?

Comment: Got it!!!  Has to be: userrequest.Projection = Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.UsersResource.ListRequest.ProjectionEnum.Full;   No idea why it's not reachable otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!! Has to be:

```
userrequest.Projection = Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.UsersResource.ListR‌​equest.ProjectionEnu‌​m.Full;
```

No idea why it's not reachable otherwise the directory context is in use anyway.

Comment: The full namespace needs to be specified, or resolveable via a `using` statement